# Is it possible to init a jQuery datatable with a variable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm trying to init a jQuery datatable with a var like below :

```
optTable    = {
        "bRetrieve":true,
        "bDestroy":true,
        "sScrollY": 220,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "180%",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "Affiche _MENU_ enregistrements par page",
            "sZeroRecords": "Rien de trouvé - désolé",
            "sInfo": "Montre _START_ à _END_ de _TOTAL_ enregistrements",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Montre 0 à 0 de 0 enregistrement",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtré de _MAX_ enregistrements au total)",
            "sSearch": "Recherche"
        }};

var boxTable = $('.boxtable').dataTable(optTable);
```

Is it impossible to do that, or maybe i made an error ?

**EDIT** : It works, certainly a syntax mistake bring the problem

Comment: it's working http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/5Zknf/ (I didn't change anything)... How do you load your javascript files and scripts ?

Comment: @LekisS Like you, but my js is in a file.js included in a file.php and js in `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: ok, but where do you load your jQuery / jQuery UI / jQuery.DataTables / file.js files ?

Comment: That seems weird, i re-did changes - moving option to optTable var - and it's working... Certainly a syntax mistake... Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. I tried your code and it worked properly. Did you get any errors?

You can check for variable "boxTable" in Firebug by using console.log:

```
...
var boxTable = $('.boxtable').dataTable(optTable);
console.log(boxTable);
```